# Storing a large amount of backend data in Android

Tags: android

I am developing a places of interest app which will display the list of places of interest in a location.

When user chooses one, it will display more information and address etc.

How do I store all this data? Currently I am using a text file to store all the data and subsequently when user chooses a place, it will parse the text file and retrieve the necessary data for display.

Any advice on what is a better way to do this? I looked at SharedPrefs, but it is more like storing "key-value" pair and in this case I need to store a large amount of data.

I want the info to be available even when the device is offline, thus I can't download from an online server upon request.

Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may store it to XML file using XML serializer, here is very good tutorial for learning that,

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-android/

and it can be easily parsed using Java XPath Api. Have a look at this at parsing XML files

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLite
It can store large data.
It is available offline.
All your problems will be sorted out.
Hre we have a wonderful tutorial for sq-lite 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: This with The Room library (recommended by android)- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Answer (score 0):

How about a relational database?

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). If you do not need database access, you could define a class what holds every information you need. Then, you can do the following:

- when you need to save the datas, you serialize your object, dumping its content to a file, for example on the SD card
- when you want to load the datas, you just load the above mentioned file, and get back everything from the dumped file

I am using this method in my app to cache some datas that would need internet access, so the user can still view it, and with proper implementation, this can work very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Use database, create table and insert all the data in it. When you need the data just fire the query, and you are done.

SQLite is fine for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of data you want to store, you could use a SQLite Database (provided with Android) if it has a normal database structure. You could Serialize your data and save it in a raw or encrypted file, making you data implement Serializable.