# How to convert large amounts of static text to array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-recyclerview, large-files

What is the most efficient way to store large amounts of text, and then -- when needed -- to convert them into an array, with each paragraph taking up one index, so to be able to attach the array to an adapter that in turn will be attached to a Recycler-view.

What makes it more complex is that I want to apply different formatting to each and every paragraph when displayed. So how would I attach the formatting instructions to its paragraph? Through a multi-dimensional array, or an array with key-value pairs?

I've thought about an SQLite database, but it seems to be overkill, especially that all the text are static and don't change (it's almost like a book app).

I was thinking of using a regular text file with all the text inside, and every paragraph should have an attached formatting instructions line, and to use a RegEx to split it up into the array. But I'm concerned about the efficiency, especially that this will be done every time the user opens the app.

Or just an .xml file? But how would I dynamically populate the array (especially that each paragraph needs to have its own formatting)?

Or should I make a ready class with a manually populated array so that it doesn't have to happen dynamically?

This is **not** a duplicate of any post, because as most of these posts are about storing large amounts of text, this is more complex. This is about how to store and retrieve complex date, not just one big flow of text. Especially that every paragraph needs to have an associated formatting tag so that in the onBindView it takes particular action depending on what the formatting tag is.

Comment: a xml file will do the trick :) https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: I'm not going to publish as an answer, but an XML file with different string names is the best way. I agree with progressive_overload

Comment: But it still leaves me with the same questions. I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: What is "large amounts", are we talking about hundreds of megabytes?

Comment: If these are "large amounts of text", perhaps you should not be loading them all at once. "So how would I attach the formatting instructions to its paragraph?" -- use HTML that works within the limits of `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing a large amount of backend data in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443057/storing-a-large-amount-of-backend-data-in-android)

Comment: No, by large amounts I don't mean hundreds of mbs, rather thousands of lines of text. And that has to be converted to an array, plus a way to associate every paragraph with its defined formatting instructions tag.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of any post, because as I said, this is more complex in that every paragraph needs to have an associated formatting tag.

Comment: Look, the best way to store that is either in a separate string class or in XML files. The XML string can be gotten by activity.getString(R.string.some_string);

Comment: I would use sqlite, you'll be glad you made this decision now when things become more complex. Then build a content provider on top of it to get the benefit of cursor loaders

Comment: "thousands of lines" does not sound much. Have you tried doing the simplest thing that works, i.e. the text file you mention?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to store this large amount of text in a String, toByte it, when called you could perform a byte read to store the bytes into an array based on the condition of a delimiter such as a line space character. Perform this and increase the array index each time.